# Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` on  some part of screen. This UIView has Pan gesture recognizer. This UIView ( mainVw)  has a `UITextView` that completely covers the UIView. This UITextview has swipe gestures(left and write).

My problem is When I swipe left or right, The UIView starts dragging also. What I want is ,when I drag the UIView it should drag and when I swipe UITextView should swipe left write but no dragging.

Here is the code  I'm using to give better understanding:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [panGesture setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    panGesture.delegate =(id)self;
    [self.mainVw addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
    //[self.mainVw.layer setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:vwCaptionBg.center] forKey:@"originalCenter"];


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer;
rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanTouch:)];
[rightRecognizer setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
rightRecognizer.delegate=(id)self;
[self.txtVw addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *vwLeftRecognizer;
vwLeftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanTouch:)];
[vwLeftRecognizer setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
vwLeftRecognizer.delegate=(id)self;
[self.txtVw addGestureRecognizer:vwLeftRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `[GESTURE requireGestureRecognizerToFail:GESTURE_TO_FAIL];` method. This would be your swipes would need to fail before the pan would be allowed to proceed.

There is also delegate methods you can use for simultaneous gestures.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

Or you could use either of these delegate methods with your own logic.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```

Comment: Hi Ryan ,Thanks for your answer, When I swipe, it just calls first for Pan gesture but I want swipe. This is the problem

Comment: Right so just require that your swipe gestures fail before the pan begins using the `[pan requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipe]`

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan, This solved my problem to 50% but still some time while swipe it starts dragging. Can you help me further

Comment: Did you do that method call for each of your swipes?

Comment: Yes is  I did this way :                                              [panGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:rightRecognizer];
    [panGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:vwLeftRecognizer];

Comment: Is it doing both or is it panning instead of swiping?